# Basis for vector space given combination of vector components

Tags: vector-spaces

The following is the first step in a homework problem of mine:

> Find a basis for the vector space $S = \{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x - y - 2z + w = 0\}$.

The actual problem involves computing the orthonormal basis using Gram-Schmidt, which I know how to do. As this is homework, I'm just looking for some information on methods that can be used to find the basis for this vector space, not the actual answer to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a linear system with 1 equation in 4 unknowns.  Hence you can think of this as having 3 free variables and one bound variable.  For each of the free variables in turn, set it equal to 1 and the other free variables to zero.  Solve for the bound variable(s).  You will get a set of vectors, that is easy to prove is independent and of the right cardinality to be a basis.

Comment: Okay that's coming back to me from my last Linear Algebra course now. So should I have three vectors in this basis, since there are three free variables?

Comment: That's right. $~$